# How to set hard line breaks in Texstudio

Tags: line-breaking, texstudio, line-spacing, editors

I am using TeXStudio in Ubuntu 18.04 as a LaTeX editor.

I need to set hard line breaks which are not just on the screen, but also written to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Options", click in "Show advanced options" (below on the left). Then, on the "Adv. Editor" tab, choose "Line wrapping" as "Hard line wrapping after max. characters" and, finally, set "Maximal characters" to the value of your liking.

[image]

Comment: As cool as this option is, it ruins `lstlisting` environments as sometimes you don't want a line break there... do you happen to know of any workaround?